# Trigger setEditing: animated: without using an edit button

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, edit, setediting

I have a `UITableView` with some custom cells in it. In these custom cells I defined a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` that triggers the edit mode of this table. So when someone presses and holds a cell for like 1.5 sec, the table goes into edit mode.

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(startEditMode:)];
```

Which triggers:

```
- (void)startEditMode:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    if (self.allowEdit) {
        UITableView *table = (UITableView *)self.superview;
        [table setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    }

}
```

But what I want to do is detect when the table goes into edit mode because I need to show/hide some additional buttons in this case. But for some reason in my viewcontroller this is never executed:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"SET EDITING");
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}
```

Any suggestion why? Is this just being called when using a proper Edit Button as provided by default in the UINavigationController?

Or how can I detect when my UITableView goes into Edit Mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're sending the message (setEditing) to the table view, you should be sending it to the view controller (presumably a UITableViewController subclass?). It will then take care of the table view for you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so in case someone else walks into this thread with the same problem, I will show you how I solved this.

In my custom `UITableViewCell` I have this method now:

```
- (void)startEditMode:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    if (self.allowEdit) {
        UITableView *table = (UITableView *)self.superview;
        UITableViewController *control = (UITableViewController *)table.dataSource;
        [control setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    }

}
```